# Split matrix in MATLAB using predefined numbers of submatrix rows

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix A

```
 1     1     0     0
 0     1     0     0
 1     0     0     1
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     1     1     1
 1     1     0     0
 1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1
```

I want this matrix to be split according to user's input say `d = [1 2 3].`

```
for i=2:length(d)
  d(i) = d(i) + d(i-1); % d = [1 3 6]
end
```

This gives `d = [1 (1+2) (1+2+3)] = d[1 3 6]`. There are 9 rows in this matrix, calculate `ceil` of `[(1/6)*9]`,  `[(3/6)*9]` and `[(6/6)*9]`. Hence this gives `[2 5 9].` First split up is first two rows , 2nd split up is next (5-2=3) 3 rows and third split is (9-5=4) 4 rows.

The output should be like:

The split up is: 1st split up->

```
      1     1     0     0    % first 2 rows in matrix A
      0     1     0     0
```

2nd split up->

```
      1     0     0     1    % next 3 rows
      0     0     1     0
      0     0     0     0
```

3rd split up->

```
      0     1     1     1    % next 4 rows
      1     1     0     0
      1     0     0     0
      0     0     0     1
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got something that works already. What's the problem/question?

Comment: do you want this to be done efficiently?

Comment: @gevang- i would like to display the output in command window. is that possible?

Comment: just type the entry you want to display, i.e. `B{1}, B{2}, B{3}`, or all of them `B{:}`.

Comment: i want it automatically displayed on the command window when i run the program.

Comment: again, put the above at the end of your script or `disp(B{i})`, looping through `i = 1:length(d)` so you can get the splits displayed. MATLAB displays arrays using `disp()` or just calling the matrix name without a semicolon `;` at the end. Even better `cellfun(@disp, B)` to avoid the loop. See update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mat2cell` with input `d = [1 2 3]` to store the final splits in separate cell arrays

```
B = mat2cell(A, d+1, size(A,2));
```

or, to adapt it to your computation of the split row sizes:

```
d = [1 2 3];
c = cumsum(d); % [1, 3, 6]

s = ceil(size(A,1)*c/c(end)); % [2, 5, 9] 
n = [s(1) diff(s)]; % [2, 3, 4]

B = mat2cell(A, n, size(A,2));
```

To display the splits you can add a command similar to:

```
cellfun(@disp, B)
```